# How do I change icon text font in Windows 11?

Tags: fonts, windows-11, desktop-icons

[image: Chrome Icon Text]

E.g., I want to remove the shadow, make it bold and/or change the font to make it more visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the registry for that - make sure you make a backup, export `CurrentVersion` (full path below).

First, open *Settings*, search for *Font* and open *Font settings*, select a font you want. The following example has the font named *MY FAV FONT*.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Segoe UI"="MY FAV FONT"
```

I do not think you should do this if you are not literate in `regedit`.

Comment: That change will replace the font "Segoe UI" for all applications, which is very much more than just the "icon text font" on the desktop.